# How to insert a column that matches id from both tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, where-clause

I have 2 tables, users and grades.
Users looks like this:

```
ID | Name | Area
1  | John | Hub
```

And grades like this:

```
ID | ID_from | ID_for | G1 | G2 | Area
1  |   23    |    22  |  9 | 8  |  NULL
```

I'd like to insert the area from the Users table into the grades table, where `users.id = grades.ID_for`.

I've already tried doing

```
INSERT INTO grades
SELECT area FROM users
where ID_for = users.id;
```

but I get "#1054 - Champ 'ID_for' inconnu dans where clause".

Comment: Error 1054, for unknown column is a MySql error, so I added the tag.

Comment: Fix your schema. You should normalise your grades table, e.g. (id,from_user_id,for_user_id,grade_category,score)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number of values needed to be provided for area table is 6 (which are `ID | ID_from | ID_for | G1 | G2 | Area`). but you are only providing 3 (which are ID | Name | Area)

you need to map all the columns from source table to destination table.

but also, It looks like you are trying to update area rather then insert. If that is the case

```
update grades 
set Area = (select area from users where users.id = grades.ID_for)
```

might do the work. If your intention is to update area's for only null values, then

```
update grades 
set Area = (select area from users where users.id = grades.ID_for) 
where area is null
```

Comment: what can I say. It is up to OP to accept it as answer :)